# get checkbox states and post changes to db by boolean value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using something similar to the following to output (true/false) checkboxes representing settings for a specific computer by means of database values.

The div will always have a unique ID value prepended by 'c' representing the computer.  Each setting for the checkboxes is either 1 or 0 representing true/false.  The output below works fine.  Now I want to allow users to change the checkboxes and submit the changes to the database by means of the 'submit settings' link.  Note that there will be multiple divs (computers) on the page such as below.

I want to use jquery onclick of the 'submit settings' link to read the div id and the states of the three settings then do an ajax post to update the values in the db.  In a perfect world I would like to open a confirmation modal after click to confirm the changes as well as give an option to use those settings as the default across ALL computers in the particular account.  For now, I am just looking for the basic and can possibly expand it to that later.

I do not know where to begin with the jquery/ajax as this is still VERY new to me, but would have no problems with the php script the values are posted to.

```
<div id="c'.$computer[computer_id].'">
    <label><input type="checkbox" '.($settings[hide_icon] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> System tray icon?</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" '.($settings['24h_format'] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> 24 hour time format?</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" '.($settings[stealth] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> Stealth mode?</label>
    <label><a href="#">Submit settings</a></label>';
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to wrap your div in a form and add names to your input checkboxes:

```
<form action="url_where_you_want_to_post" method="POST">
    <div id="c'.$computer[computer_id].'">
        <label><input name="hide_icon" type="checkbox" '.($settings[hide_icon] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> System tray icon?</label>
        <label><input name="24h_format" type="checkbox" '.($settings['24h_format'] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> 24 hour time format?</label>
        <label><input name="stealth" type="checkbox" '.($settings[stealth] == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked').'> Stealth mode?</label>
        <label><a href="#" class="submit">Submit settings</a></label>';
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.submit').on('click', function () {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');

            $.ajax({
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize()
            }).done(function (response) {
                // Depending on what you return from the server you can show some feedback for the user.
                // If you return lets say { success: true } from the server, then you can do:
                if (response.success) {
                    alert('Saved!');
                } else {
                    alert('Some error occurred.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... that will definitely help me out with the ajax and looks pretty simple actually.  So, I do not need to collect my variables with jquery then... I can just post the values as I normally would?

Comment: Yep, this is the key line for posting all 3 checkboxes: `data: $form.serialize()`. Do a var_dump($_POST) in your php script and you will see what is the structure of the posted data.

Comment: awesome... I'll be able to do the processing file easily then.  Off the top of my head I am going to add a hidden field with the computer id as I will need that.  Assuming I add in another checkbox for 'apply to all' I can apply them to all as well.  Now, assuming the latter and I do apply settings to all... how can I update the checkboxes on the page after completion?  Would this be handled in the success result above?

Comment: You mean you want to have an extra checkbox that if you check it checks/unchecks all the other 3 checkboxes (hide_icon, 24h_format, stealth)?

Comment: No, it would replicate the values for that particular div on all the others.  In my op I only listed one div, but there could be any number of them each in the same format.